# How to take values from given JSON in swift2.3

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift, nsjsonserialization

let result = try?NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,options:.MutableContainers)

How to take values from given `JSON` in swift2.3

```
({
       FirstName:"sample"
       LastName:"Data"
    },
    {
       FirstName:"sample1"
       LastName:"Data1"
 })
```

How can I take value from first name and add to array swift 2.3 and Xcode8

Comment: Please show us what you have try.

Comment: how to add First name to one array. I mean how to iterate.

Comment: For that first you need to show us that how you have parse your json.

Comment: @NiravD : i update the question

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this with **json** is the json dictionary

```
let firstname = json["FirstName"] as! String
```

Comment: Look closely at OP's data: they have an *array* of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

The following code converts your given json into string then uses NSJSONSerialization to parse your json and finally print the values of FirstName and Lastname

```
let jsonString = "[{\"FirstName\":\"sample\",\"LastName\":\"Data\"},{\"FirstName\":\"sample1\",\"LastName\":\"Data1\"}]"
if let serializedJsonArray = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: .MutableContainers),
let parsedJsonArray = serializedJsonArray as? [[String:AnyObject]]{
for jsonArray in parsedJsonArray {
    if let firstName = jsonArray["FirstName"] as? String{
        print(firstName)
    }
    if let lastName = jsonArray["LastName"] as? String{
        print(lastName)
    }
}
}
```

Hope this helps.